# Ansible: 'user' module 'update_password' register not returning 'rc'

Tags: ansible

I am resetting Linux user password as below and it resets password. But the register variable `resetPwOp` does not contain the attribute `rc`.

```yaml
- name: reset pw linux
  user:
    name: "{{ userid }}"
    update_password: always
    password: "{{ passwd | password_hash('sha512') }}"
  register: resetPwOp
  when: (unlockUserOp is defined) and (unlockUserOp.rc == 0)
```

The task completes successfully.

```yaml
TASK [reset pw linux] **********************************************************
changed: [72.118.19.24]
```

When I try to check `resetPwOp.rc == 0`, I get `'dict object' has no attribute 'rc'` but other attributes like `shell`, `name`, `changed`, etc. are available.

`resetPwOp` has these values:

```json
"msg": "resetpwop linux: {u'comment': u'72923', u'shell': u'/bin/bash', u'group': 10115, u'name': u'user1', u'changed': True, 'failed': False, u'state': u'present', u'home': u'/home/user1', u'move_home': False, u'password': u'NOT_LOGGING_PASSWORD', u'append': False, u'uid': 1150}
```

How to be sure the password update successful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *But the register variable `resetPwOp` does not contain the attribute `rc`.*

Right, that's the expected behavior. According the documentation Common [Return Values](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/common_return_values.html)

> *Ansible modules normally return a data structure that can be registered into a variable, or seen directly when output by the ansible program. Each module can optionally document its own unique return values ...*

and [`user` module – Manage user accounts - Return Values](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/user_module.html#return-values), there is no such vaule.

This is because for [`rc`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/common_return_values.html#rc)

> *Some modules execute command line utilities or are geared for executing commands directly (`raw`, `shell`, `command`, and so on), this field contains ‘return code’ of these utilities.*

---

> *How to be sure the password update successful?*

If the task executed without errors. This is because the parameter [`update_password`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/user_module.html#parameter-update_password)

> *`always` will update passwords if they differ.*

and then you may have a look also into [`changed_when`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html#defining-changed) and [`failed_when`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html#defining-failure).

Comment: So how to be sure the password update successful. resetPwOp has these values. "msg": "resetpwop linux: {u'comment': u'72923', u'shell': u'/bin/bash', u'group': 10115, u'name': u'user1', u'changed': True, 'failed': False, u'state': u'present', u'home': u'/home/user1', u'move_home': False, u'password': u'NOT_LOGGING_PASSWORD', u'append': False, u'uid': 1150}